# how to call lua method by method name

Tags: lua

there is an object `client` which has many method, methods could be call like `client:hget(key, field)` or `client:exists(key)` etc.

Now, I need implement a function `client_holder.call(cmd, ...)`

```
local client = client_instance;
function call(cmd, ...)
    client[cmd](client, ...) // will this work??
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should work. As the Lua manual [states](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.4.9), the colon notation is just syntactic sugar:

> The form
>
> ```
> functioncall ::= prefixexp ‘:’ Name args
> ```
>
> can be used to call "methods". A call v:name(args) is syntactic sugar for v.name(v,args), except that v is evaluated only once.